# How can I get data from my Shared-hosted server in my flutter app?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, e-commerce

I can't get data from the my host-shared server in flutter app but I can get them in PostMan, it worked on local hosting via Xampp but I can't get any data from my server.

Here are some points:

The Postman results (ok 200)

[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixYy4.jpg)

Flutter can't get products from the server:

[flutter cant get products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAuoS.jpg)

My `.htaccess` file in the main and the public files in the picture.

[.htacces and /public/.htaccess files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7482.jpg)

My laravel site (works fine and I can get products from database)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USmw.jpg)

My `.env` file (I have cropped only the important details)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqIq.jpg)

My Cpanel file manager in server:

[file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DX9b.jpg)

My `/public/` folder file manager:

[/Public/ folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FkOw.jpg)

Is there any solution?

The problem is from the server not the flutter app because I tried someones else server and it worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Get data with queryParameters,

like this example.

```
final queryParameters = {
'username' : username,
};

final uri = Uri.http('http://example.com','/your sub page',queryParameters);

final response = await http.get(uri,
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/application-json",
},);
```

**its work for me**